# I locked one axis in edit mode and don't know how to unlock

Tags: edit-mode, axis

I just have a simple plane and I can't move it in z axis.
even if I rotate it, it just shrinks onto its self. Rotates normal in object mode
and the weird lock seams to follow the objects orientation from object mode

I must have hit some shortcut by accident but I can't figure it out.
plis help

Answer (score 0):

Omg it was scaled to 0 on its flat surface... and I could not see it
My bad XD